# How to integrate Zendframework 2 library with Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

How can I integrate zendframework 2 library with my Symfony 2 application? How to autoload and how to use it? I would like to use some classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To integrate Zendframework 2 into Symfony 2, If you're using the Symfony Standard Distribution, add the following to the deps file at the root of your project:

```
[zf2]
    git=https://github.com/zendframework/zf2.git
```

Now, update the vendor libraries by running:

```
php bin/vendors update
```

If you are not using Symfony Standard Distribution, you will have to clone from github in vendor folder.

Next, add the Zend namespace to the app/autoload.php file so that these libraries can be autoloaded.

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    ...
    'Zend' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/zf2/library',
));
```

Then It's done, You can use zendframework library. For example I will show Zend\Json class usage in the default symfony 2 application. 
Open src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php and edit indexAction method the code like below:

```
use Zend\Json\Json;
...
public function indexAction()
{
    $data = array('zendframework2' => 'symfony2');
    $encodedData = Json::encode($data);
    var_dump($encodedData);
    return array();
}
```

In this example I am using a zendframework class to convert an array to json

Comment: For completeness: if you're using 2.1, you simply need to add `zendframework/zendframework` to your composer.json and do an update.

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony 2.1 you'll need to add `zendframework/zendframework` under `require` in `composer.json`. If you only want a few packages and not the whole library, you should add the url to the Zend libraries under `repositories`, like so:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],
"require": {
    //...
    "zendframework/zend-log":"2.*",
```